# Prevent ajax form to call server on client side errors

Tags: jquery, ajax, forms, asp.net-mvc-3, validation

I have a form which i use on submit button to get some values and return a partial with those values.

In the page i've included jquery validation and unobtrusive .. to validate on client side, which does good, it validates, but server is still called, how can i avoid it?

```
@using (Html.BeginForm("Index", "Search", FormMethod.Post, new { role = "form", @class = "form-horizontal", id = "SearchForm" }))
{
    @Html.AntiForgeryToken();
    @Html.EditorFor(m => m.Test);

    <div class="form-group">
        <div class="col-sm-offset-2 col-sm-10">
            <button type="submit" class="btn btn-default">@Base.Search</button>
        </div>
    </div>
}               

@Scripts.Render("~/bundles/jqueryval")
@Scripts.Render("~/bundles/jqueryui")

$('#SearchForm').on('submit', function (evt) {
    evt.preventDefault();
    $.post('/Search/Index', $(this).serialize(), function (response) {
        $('#searchResults').html(response);
    });
});
```

And here is my controller

```
[ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult Index(SearchModel searchModel)
{
    if (ModelState.IsValid)
    {
        return PartialView("SearchResults", searchModel);
    }

    return null;
}
```

Comment: And where is this clientside validation ?

Comment: It is there, just forgot to copy )

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried

```
$('#SearchForm').on('submit', function (evt) {
    evt.preventDefault();

    if(!$(evt.currentTarget).valid())
        return false;

    $.post('/Search/Index', $(this).serialize(), function (response) {
        $('#searchResults').html(response);
    });
});
```

Must be just jquery validation for this though.